# How can I call a specific function at program start using MinGW compiler?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

**My Code**      : A Program to Print from a to z
**My file name** : ft_print_alphabet.c

```
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void ft_print_alphabet(void)
{
    char c;
    c = 'a';
    while (c <= 'z')
    {
        ft_putchar(c);
        c++;
    }
}
```

**My Issue:**

I use the **MinGW** & **Vim editor** and I get the following error while I compile in MinGW.

```
$ gcc ft_print_alphabet.c
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x2e): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I understand that the compiler doesn't know from where it should start the program since it couldn't locate `void main()` in the code.

My code works fine when I replace `ft_print_alphabet(void)` with `void main(void)` but please note this is the standard way of coding where I am going to apply for a c coding camp.

This code and ***the function ft_print_alphabet(void) 'must' be used***. I know there are other simple ways to do the same code but please note I'm not looking for using the function `ft_print_alphabet(void)`.

How can I execute the program without adding `void main()` instead of `void ft_print_alphabet(void)`.

I need my program to start executing from the function `void ft_print_alphabet(void)`. How can I do that please? Is there any command like:

`gcc ft_print_alphabet.c | ft_print_alphabet` ?

`gcc ft_print_alphabet.c ft_print_alphabet` ?

Something like this?

Comment: "the function `ft_print_alphabet(void)` 'must' be used" - AFAIK, `main` also _must_ be defined. In fact, your libC is most likely hard-coded to call the `main` function when launching any executable.

Comment: also note that it is not `void main()`, it is `int main()`.

Comment: I tested that the answer by Ciro Santilli on the linked thread works in mingw-w64

Comment: Have you tried `gcc -Dft_print_alphabet=main ft_print_alphabet.c`?